# Type mismatch Outlook.MAPIFolder and Object (Error 13)

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I never played with VBA before. This script below is supposed to save all email details in an Outlook folder onto an Excel spreadsheet.

I'm getting error 13 when I execute `Set msg = itm`. The value of `itm` at break time corresponds to a *meeting invitation*, so not your ordinary *email*. Could that be the problem? If so, how do I tell VBA to ignore anything that's not a plain email?

```
Sub ExportToExcel()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim strSheet As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim intRowCounter As Integer
Dim intColumnCounter As Integer
Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim nms As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim fld As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim itm As Object
    strSheet = "OutlookItems.xls"
    strPath = Environ("UserProfile")
    strSheet = strPath & "\Downloads\" & strSheet
Debug.Print strSheet
  'Select export folder
Set nms = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set fld = nms.PickFolder
  'Handle potential errors with Select Folder dialog box.
If fld Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "There are no mail messages to export", vbOKOnly, _
    "Error"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf fld.DefaultItemType <> olMailItem Then
    MsgBox "There are no mail messages to export", vbOKOnly, _
    "Error"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf fld.Items.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "There are no mail messages to export", vbOKOnly, _
    "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If
  'Open and activate Excel workbook.
Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
appExcel.Workbooks.Open (strSheet)
Set wkb = appExcel.ActiveWorkbook
Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)
wks.Activate
appExcel.Application.Visible = True
  'Copy field items in mail folder.
For Each itm In fld.Items
intColumnCounter = 1
Set msg = itm
intRowCounter = intRowCounter + 1
Set rng = wks.Cells(intRowCounter, intColumnCounter)
rng.Value = msg.To
intColumnCounter = intColumnCounter + 1
Set rng = wks.Cells(intRowCounter, intColumnCounter)
rng.Value = msg.SenderEmailAddress
intColumnCounter = intColumnCounter + 1
Set rng = wks.Cells(intRowCounter, intColumnCounter)
rng.Value = msg.Subject
intColumnCounter = intColumnCounter + 1
Set rng = wks.Cells(intRowCounter, intColumnCounter)
rng.Value = msg.SentOn
intColumnCounter = intColumnCounter + 1
Set rng = wks.Cells(intRowCounter, intColumnCounter)
rng.Value = msg.ReceivedTime
Next itm

Set appExcel = Nothing
Set wkb = Nothing
Set wks = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing
Set msg = Nothing
Set nms = Nothing
Set fld = Nothing
Set itm = Nothing
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:  If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    MsgBox strSheet & " doesn't exist", vbOKOnly, _
    "Error"
    ElseIf Err.Number = 13 Then
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": Type mismatch", vbOKOnly, _
    "Error"
    Else
    MsgBox Err.Number & "; Description: ", vbOKOnly, _
    "Error"
End If

Set appExcel = Nothing
Set wkb = Nothing
Set wks = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing
Set msg = Nothing
Set nms = Nothing
Set fld = Nothing
Set itm = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to process `MailItem` objects, check the Class property - all Outlook Object Model objects implement it. It will be `olMail` (= 43) for the `MailItem` objects:

```
If itm.Class = 43 Then 'olMail
  Set msg = itm
  ...
```